# multiple radio button not selecting evenly in a group of four radio button

Tags: angular

In an angular snippets, a group of radio buttons is not clicking evenly. The number of radio buttons with the name is four but only the first and the last radio buttons is clicking. Below is my snippet

```html
<div class="grouped fields">
  <label>Please confirm your company type by ticking the appropriate 
                  box below (Only one box must be ticked).</label>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type" type="radio" name="typeC" checked="checked" id="100" [value]="true">
      <label for="100">A OPTION</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type" type="radio" name="typeC" id="101" [value]="false">
      <label for="101">B OPTION</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type" type="radio" name="typeC" id="102" [value]="false">
      <label for="102">C OPTION</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type" type="radio" name="typeC" id="103" [value]="false">
      <label for="103">D OPTION </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please how can I ensure that only one is ticked at choice

Comment: [value]="false" ?

Comment: defualting it to false, so that at first only one is selected

Comment: Your value attribute for each `radio input` should be unique. Check out this example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfpdj9?file=src/app/list-selection-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

You have a radio button bound to `false`. The value should be bound to the value you expect the radio button to return

### Solution

You simply need to set unique values for the input, something like `[value]="100"`

```html
<div class="grouped fields">
    <label>Please confirm your company type by ticking the appropriate 
                  box below (Only one box must be ticked).</label>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type"
                    type="radio" name="typeC" checked="checked" id="100" [value]="100">
            <label for="100">A OPTION</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type"
                    type="radio" name="typeC" id="101" [value]="101">
            <label for="101">B OPTION</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type"
                    type="radio" name="typeC" id="102" [value]="102">
            <label for="102">C OPTION</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input [(ngModel)]="aData.type"
                    type="radio" name="typeC" id="103" [value]="103">
            <label for="103">D OPTION </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

See this [Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7f5y8x)